# Updating Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel on AWS

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and using Kernel level 4.15 on one of EC2 instance.
I need to upgrade Kernel to 5.4.0 Kernel.
But when I see available packages I see only available version as

```
apt list -a linux-aws
linux-aws/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.4.0.1061.44 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.1021.21]
linux-aws/now 4.15.0.1021.21 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.4.0.1061.44]
linux-aws/bionic 4.15.0.1007.7 amd64
```

I was asked to go to 5.4.0.1054 (specific version).
How should I move to 5.4.0.1054 when I don't see its available on Ubuntu repo.
Does Ubuntu not maintain all Kernel Version, but only maintain latest?

Thanks
Vish

Comment: Try enabling Universe repository using: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)